# Can the angle of incidence be greater than 90°?

Tags: geometric-optics

My teacher was teaching me prism in Ray Optics and he told me that for the emergence of ray from a prism the condition is :

$i_{g}≤i≤90°$

where $i_{g}$ is the angle of incidence for which grazing refracted ray is obtained and $i$ is the angle of incidence. Now, my question is what will happen if angle of incidence is more than $90°$? Why,  for emergence of ray,  angle of incidence should be less than $90°$? Can the angle of incidence even be greater than $90°$? Does it make sense for the angle of incidence to be greater than $90°$? In general, for any reflection or refraction can the angle of incidence be greater than $90°$? Please explain. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

The angle of incidence is the angle between the normal line orthogonal to the surface of the prism (i.e., coming straight out from the prism) and the direction of the incident ray. For all intents and purposes we can consider the prism to have a straight edge, so that the normal line simply makes a right angle with that straight edge.

If the angle of incidence is $0^\circ$, the light is exactly along the normal line. If the angle increases, the pie wedge between the normal line and the incident ray gets bigger. When the angle approaches $90^\circ$, the incident ray is almost parallel to the prism - we know this because the angle between the normal line and the prism's edge is exactly $90^\circ$. Once the angle equals $90^\circ$, the incident ray just travels parallel to the prism, but never really gets closer to it! And if the angle is greater than $90^\circ$, that means that the light is incident from *inside* the prism! So that is a completely different scenario, the scenario of light travelling from inside of a prism to outside of a prism, and in that scenario we typically just reverse the whole problem and define the angle of incidence from a normal line inside of the prism. Any time that the incident light is actually going into the prism, the angle will always be less than $90^\circ$.

Comment: So, do you mean that the angle of incidence can never be greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{π}{2}$ instead of $\frac{π}{4}$?

Comment: Oops yes! Will edit the comment

Comment: So yes, the angle of incidence cannot be greater than $\pi/2$.